# Disable automatic migrations in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have my **Configuration** class constructor like this:

```
public Configuration() => AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
```

And I have even updated my **DbContent** to this:

```
public DatabaseContext()
    : base("DefaultConnection")
{
    Database.CommandTimeout = 900;
    Database.Log = s => Debug.WriteLine(s);
    Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<DatabaseContext>());
}
```

But when I try to run `update-database` for a specific migration:

```
update-database -TargetMigration CreateOrganisation
```

I get this:

> Applying explicit migrations: [201805081508118_CreateOrganisation].
>
> Applying explicit migration: 201805081508118_CreateOrganisation.
>
> Applying automatic migration: 201805081508117_CreateOrganisation_AutomaticMigration.

The last one it runs, then fails because it states:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): There is already an object named 'Answers' in the database.

Which there is, but the actual migration looks like this:

```
public partial class CreateOrganisation : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
                "dbo.Organisations",
                c => new
                {
                    Id = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 100),
                    Name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 100),
                    Description = c.String(maxLength: 255),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

        AddColumn("dbo.Users", "OrganisationId", c => c.String(maxLength: 100));
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropTable("dbo.Organisations");
        DropColumn("dbo.Users", "OrganisationId");
    }
}
```

As you can see, there is no mention of **Answer** in that migration, which leads me to assume it is trying to do the prior migrations....

Does anyone know how I can stop that?

---

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // Table renames
    modelBuilder.Entity<Criteria>().ToTable("Criteria");
    modelBuilder.Entity<Formula>().ToTable("Formulas");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Roles");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("UserRoles");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaims");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogins");
    modelBuilder.Entity<ImageText>().ToTable("ImageText");

    // One to Many  
    modelBuilder.Entity<Criteria>().HasMany(m => m.Attributes).WithOptional().HasForeignKey(m => m.CriteriaId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasMany(m => m.Users).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(m => m.RoleId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Organisation>().HasMany(m => m.Feeds).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(m => m.OrganisationId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Organisation>().HasMany(m => m.Users).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(m => m.OrganisationId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Group>().HasMany(m => m.Questions).WithOptional().HasForeignKey(m => m.GroupId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Question>().HasMany(m => m.Answers).WithOptional().HasForeignKey(m => m.QuestionId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().HasMany(m => m.PriorityColours).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(m => m.CategoryId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().HasMany(m => m.Criteria).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(m => m.CategoryId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().HasMany(m => m.Feeds).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(m => m.CategoryId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().HasMany(m => m.Quotes).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(m => m.CategoryId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().HasMany(m => m.QuestionGroups).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(m => m.CategoryId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(m => m.Searches).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(m => m.UserId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(m => m.Charges).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(m => m.UserId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Answer>().HasMany(m => m.Images).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(m => m.AnswerId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Image>().HasMany(m => m.ImageText).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(m => m.ImageId);

    // Create our primary keys
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey(m => m.UserId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasKey(m => m.Id);
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(m => new {m.RoleId, m.UserId});
}
```

As requested

Comment: None of those answers solve my issue

Comment: Can we see how your OnModelCreating look like?

Comment: The "duplicate" that you mentioned, doesn't work because when I try to create a new migration, it tells me I still have some outstanding. I want to commit them one by one, because they have a foreign key which doesn't exist yet. So i created separate migrations so I could populate the data after the nullable field was added, before it was turned into a foreign key.

Comment: You can try `-verbose` switch to see what exactly is going on.

Answer (score 3):

Seems you are meet the same problem like me and I found the answer in below link, it is work for me and hope it also work for you:

[Update-Database tries to do an automatic migration even with automatic migrations disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12341470/update-database-tries-to-do-an-automatic-migration-even-with-automatic-migration)

The essential part of the answer I copy to here:

> Entity framework will always run an automatic migration before it runs an explicit migration that has the Source property defined in its .resx file, even if AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false. An explicit migration will only have the Source property set if it is created after an automatic migration has been run.
>
> The upshot is that disabling automatic migrations only means that EF won't automatically upgrade your schema when it detects model changes - but it might still do an automatic migration if it needs to fill in a gap between some explicit migrations. To avoid this behavior, don't use a mixture of automatic migrations and explicit migrations.

And the flowing steps is what I have done to resolve this problem:

- locate to the missing migration file's resx file
- open it and remove the source property. it is better if you can make a copy of this resx file.
- run the command `update-database -verbose` again.
- the pending migration will add to _migrationHistory table.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only 
answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: thanks for your advice, since I am a novice and will pay more attention on how to answer questions.