# Why is my database being updated when AutomaticMigrationsEnabled is false?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, azure-devops

From reading the docs and whatnot related to EF I thought by simply setting AutomaticMigrationsEnabled=false then I'd have to run my migrations manually (which is what I want) - this works locally and I get an error if I try to instantiate a DbContext when the db is out-of-date.

The problem is when I deploy my code to production (I've set up some CI scripts in azure devops) it somehow mysteriously updates the database. I'm really unsure what could be causing it...some sort of special behaviour when IIS and SQL Server talk to each other? Some special behaviour on EF's own part? I really don't get it...

Here is the relevant code:

```
internal class MyDbMigrations : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyDbContext>
{
    static ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(nameof(MyDbMigrations));

    public MyDbMigrations()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        MigrationsDirectory = @"Migrations";
    }
}

internal class MyDbConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public MyDbConfiguration()
    {
        SetDatabaseInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyDbContext, MyDbMigrations>(useSuppliedContext: true));
    }
}

[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MyDbConfiguration))]
internal class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext() : base(configThing.GetConnectionString())
    {
    }
}
```

My last resort is going to be tweak the permissions so nothing is allowed to touch the __MigrationHistory table, but I'd like to find out how/where it's getting updated.

Edit: here is the yaml for the devops pipeline that deploys the website.

Step 1: IIS webapp manage:

```
variables:
  PhysicalPath: 'xxx'
  ServiceAccount: 'xxx'

steps:
- task: IISWebAppManagementOnMachineGroup@0
  displayName: 'IIS Web App Manage'
  inputs:
    IISDeploymentType: '$(Parameters.IISDeploymentType)'
    ActionIISWebsite: '$(Parameters.ActionIISWebsite)'
    WebsiteName: '$(Parameters.WebsiteName)'
    WebsitePhysicalPath: '$(PhysicalPath)'
    AddBinding: '$(Parameters.AddBinding)'
    Bindings: '$(Parameters.Bindings)'
    CreateOrUpdateAppPoolForWebsite: '$(Parameters.CreateOrUpdateAppPoolForWebsite)'
    AppPoolNameForWebsite: '$(Parameters.AppPoolNameForWebsite)'
    AppPoolIdentityForWebsite: SpecificUser
    AppPoolUsernameForWebsite: '$(ServiceAccount)'
    AppPoolPasswordForWebsite: '$(ServiceAccountPw)'
    ParentWebsiteNameForVD: '$(Parameters.WebsiteName)'
    VirtualPathForVD: '$(Parameters.VirtualPathForApplication)'
    ParentWebsiteNameForApplication: '$(Parameters.WebsiteName)'
    VirtualPathForApplication: '$(Parameters.VirtualPathForApplication)'
    AppPoolName: '$(Parameters.AppPoolName)'
```

Step 2: IIS webapp deploy:

```
steps:
- task: IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroup@0
  displayName: 'IIS Web App Deploy'
  inputs:
    WebSiteName: '$(Parameters.WebsiteName)'
    Package: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\_myrepo\drop\myWebsite\bin\Release\net471\publish'
    RemoveAdditionalFilesFlag: true
    TakeAppOfflineFlag: true
```

Comment: Please share your pipeline with us.

Comment: Hi, I've added the yaml for the deployment pipeline

Comment: @DNg Entity framework will always run an automatic migration before it runs an explicit migration that has the `Source` property defined in its `.resx` file, even if `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false`. Here is a [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12341470/update-database-tries-to-do-an-automatic-migration-even-with-automatic-migration) you can refer to.